# Getting lowest valued duplicated columns only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: `value` and `product`. There will be duplicated products, but with different values. What I want to do is to get all products, but remove any duplication. The condition to remove duplication will be to get the row with the lowest value and drop the rest. For example, I want something like this:

Before:

```
product  value
A        25
B        45
C        15
C        14 
C        13
B        22
```

After

```
product  value
A        25
B        22
C        13
```

How can I make it so that only the lowest valued duplicated columns get added in the new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby('product').first()
#         value
#product       
#A           25
#B           22
#C           13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
res = df.sort_values('values').drop_duplicates('product')
```

Answer (score 0):

While going through the requirement i see , even you don't need to use `drop.duplicate` and `sort_values` as we are looking for the least minimum value of each `product` column in the dataFrame. So, there are couple ways doing it as follows...

I believe one of the shorted way will looking at the unique index by using `pandas.DataFrame.idxmin`.

```
>>> df
  product  value
0       A     25
1       B     45
2       C     15
3       C     14
4       C     13
5       B     22

>>> df.loc[df.groupby('product')['value'].idxmin()]
  product  value
0       A     25
5       B     22
4       C     13
```

## OR

> In this case another shortest and elegant way around using `Compute min of group values` using `groupby.min()` :

```
>>> df
  product  value
0       A     25
1       B     45
2       C     15
3       C     14
4       C     13
5       B     22

>>> df.groupby('product').min()
         value
product
A           25
B           22
C           13
```